# MVT doesn't extend to complex derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis

**Let $f(z)=z^3$. For $z_1=1$ and $z_2=i$ prove that there doesn't exist any complex number $c$ on the line segment joining $z_1,z_2$, such that $$\frac{f(z_1)-f(z_2)}{z_1-z_2}=f'(c).$$**

A general point in the line segment joining $1$ and $i$ is $c=t+(1-t)i$ where $t\in(0,1)$. So do we need to find $f'(z)$ and then putting $c$ in that complex quadratic deduce that it ha no root for $t\in(0,1)$?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It holds that $\frac{f(1)-f(i)}{1-i}=\frac{1+i}{1-i}=\frac{(1+i)^2}{(1-i)(1+i)}=i$.
Now the points on the line segment are $c(t)=t+(1-t)i$,

and 
$f'(c(t))=3(c(t))^2=3(t^2+2t(1-t)i-(1-t)^2)=3(2t(1-t)i-1+2t)=:a(t)$.

Now it holds that $Re(a(t))=0$ iff $t=\frac{1}{2}$, but $a(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{3}{2}i\neq i$, so there doesn't exist any $t\in [0,1]$ such that $f'(c(t))=i$.

Comment: $\frac{1+i}{1-i}\neq2$, it is actually $i$, but its OK, your method has served my purpose. Thank you.

Comment: just corrected it.